# Race condition in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, foreach, media, invoke, playlist

I need to play all videos in a playlist so I came up with this code.

```
Foreach ($line in get-content playlist) 
{ $line | invoke-item  }
```

Which should go through the file and play each line using the default player.

The problem that it creates a race condition, the processes will start and end so fast that one can only see the last file.

How to overcome this, I tried /path/to/player $line | out-null but the player will stop and needs user intervention in order to proceed.

Comment: Why not use vlc with it's playlist feature?

Comment: Why not just do `mpc-hc64.exe /play "yourplaylist.pls" /fullscreen`

Comment: Because I need to send keystrokes to some files but I am trying to do one step at a time in order to prevent downvoting

Answer (score 2):

I would not call this a race condition but the problem that `Invoke-Item` does not wait for the process to finish. Try to use `Start-Process -wait` instead.

Update: since it is hard to make Windows Media Player exit after the movie finishes, you could try to invoke vlc instead:

```
Foreach ($line in get-content pl.txt)
{  Start-Process -wait "C:\...\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -ArgumentList "$line vlc://quit" }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will do the same as my solution, stop at the end of each file and wait for a user click

Comment: It might be as simple as running the file in the program you want. Such as `&"c:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe” $line`    just put a space between wmplayer and $line. The & may or may not be needed. Because it might run. The path as a string. You could use single quotes instead. IIRC

Comment: @user10191234 Which media player do you use?

Comment: I am using media player classic, as for Robert's answer, still the same problem and files are starting randomly

Comment: @user10191234 Could you please try the suggestion in my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should approach the problem differently and use the parameters for `Media player classic`. I don't have it installed here, but this code should give you the general idea:

1. Make sure all your files are in the same folder
2. This will play all the files in that folder `mpc-hc64.exe "c:\mpcfiles" /play`

More information [here](https://forums.afterdawn.com/threads/launch-mpc-from-command-line-with-parameters.743773/).

Comment: Thanks, but I am resorting to a playlist because there are many subfolders and the playlist is a result of a gci command and a sorting option     gci /path -recurse |sort-object